# Problems using local printer via RDP on windows 2003 sever

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, remote-desktop, network-printer

The client is windows 7 machine, it have local printer attached. Necessary check-boxes are checked (at "share local resources" in remote desktop connection configuration windows), but the printer not appearing in "printers and faxes".

Questions: Do I need to install drivers for this printer?
What drivers should I install? For server, client or both?
If it willn't work natively, is it possible to use this printer using any 3-rd party programs (both computers server and client are behind the NAT)?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install on server the same version of drivers you have on client. It's not necessary to add printer on server, just install drivers.

Also it's possible with 3-rd part software like [ScrewDrivers](http://www.tricerat.com/products/screwdrivers) but anyway you should install it on server and on client.

Windows 2008 Server Terminal Services offer Easy Print feature which allow to print from RDP session or RemoteApp application without installing printer drivers server on server.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 2003 remote desktop, the server must have the printer drivers installed in order to use the remote printers.

You need to install the drivers ON the server FOR the server. So install the drivers for Windows 2003 on your server.

Beware about lots of cheap printers which require direct connection to the printer. You can't use them with remote desktop. You can sometimes tweak things but this is not garanteed.

edit: as stated by Sergey, you only have to install the drivers. Installing the printers is not mandatory.